# GAE unable to get serving url from app

Tags: google-app-engine

**On Application A**

I used the BlobStore API to upload an image into Google Cloud Storage (GCS). And from the same application, I am able to get serving URL using the image's cloud storage file name (eg. `"/gs/bucket-name/object-file-name"`)

**On Application B**

I tried get serving URL by using the same file name. But I'm getting a `ImagesServiceFailureException` and it seems quite clear that this is due to access permissions.

However, I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with the permissions. Under my Google APIs project, I had added both GAE apps as a Team member with `Can edit` permissions. And my understanding is that The project owners and project writers group have FULL_CONTROL permission on the object (according to https://developers.google.com/console/help/#DifferentRoles)

Is `getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName("object_name"))` strictly for images uploaded within the same GAE app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the usual `getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobKey))`. Instead of `getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(gsFileName))`.

Important to note that this blob key is generated using BlobstoreService's createGsBlobKey, and it is not the usual blob key.